# CSS : Border in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, border

I have dialog with html :

```
<div id="sample">
<div class="sample-wraper">
    <a class="modal_close" href="#"></a>
    <form id="Form1" name="Form1" method="post">
      <table id="tt"> 
        <tr align="center">
          <td colspan="2" id="naam"><b>Cha test</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <div id="boodschap" class="text" style="border-right: 1px solid; border-top: 1px solid; overflow: auto;
              border-left: 1px solid; width: 468px;  height: 182px; border-bottom: 1px solid; 
              background-color: white">njnknkkm</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">        
              <textarea id="antwoord" name="antwoord" class="text" 
                style="width: 465px; height: 182px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;" 
                onkeydown="textCounter(antwoord,aantal,1000)" 
                onkeyup="textCounter(antwoord,aantal,1000)"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text" align="left" width="210">
            Caráters permitidas
            <input readonly type="text" name="aantal" size="3" maxlength="4" value="1000" id="aantal"></td>
          <td align="right">
            <input id="Submit" name="Submit" type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="submitForm();"
              class="button" style="width: 130px">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input id="IdTo" name="IdTo" type="hidden">
    </form>
</div>
```

and css like this :

```
    #sample {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border: 1px solid;
    display: none;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px;
    position:absolute !important;
}

.modal_close {
    background: url("Close-icon-download-182005456677-png/button.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='Close-icon-download-182005456677-png/button.png',sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='Close-icon-download-182005456677-png/button.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Problem is that in IE8 on this dialog in top-left corner i get some square, which disappears if i remove border from dialog (#sample).

http://clip2net.com/s/i6klpi (sample of problem)

In IE7 and IE9 i didn't get this "feature" in corner.

---

I found this post about problem with IE borders http://www.brasee.com/displayPost.htm?postId=64. As my dialog is with position absolute (this is for not moving dialog when scrolls) i add wrapper of this dialog. So i set for dialog position relative and for wrapper position absolute. But this also didn't help. Get this result: clip2net.com/s/i6lcKz

Comment: Have you validated your html? I only see one div close tag here. Having valid html is step one.

Comment: @Ethan close tag added just it is invisible. don't not why... but now it's ok

Comment: Have you inspected it?

Comment: @AymanSafadi Do you mean existing html? Yes, i check it.